# Connection refused: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9074 (*) failed

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-503, fpm

I'm using multiple versions of PHP (7.2 and 7.4) in Mac OS. So I use `PHP-fpm` to work with 7.4 version. few weeks before I went very well but now I got an error like

```
503 Service Unavailable 
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

Then I checked my apache error log like below

```
[pid 13899] (61)Connection refused: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9074 (*) failed
[Fri Jul 31 17:42:39.724698 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 13899] [client 127.0.0.1:51458] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
```

My virtual host configurations are given below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName project.test
       ServerAlias www.project.test
       ServerAdmin web@project
       DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/projects/my_project/public/"
       # ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9074//Library/WebServer/Documents/projects/my_project/public/$1
       
       ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/project-error_log"
       CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/project-access_log" common
       
   # RewriteEngine on
   
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
           # SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
           SetHandler proxy:fcgi://localhost:9074
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/projects/my_project">
       Options +FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
    SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
    </Directory>

    
    <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
                ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
                ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
        #RedirectMatch 404 /*.sh$|/*.bak$|/vendor//*|/\.git*|/db/*|/DB_OLD/*|/composer.json|/composer.lock|/composer.phar$  
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

part of www.conf given below

```
[www]

; Per pool prefix
; It only applies on the following directives:
; - 'access.log'
; - 'slowlog'
; - 'listen' (unixsocket)
; - 'chroot'
; - 'chdir'
; - 'php_values'
; - 'php_admin_values'
; When not set, the global prefix (or /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.0) applies instead.
; Note: This directive can also be relative to the global prefix.
; Default Value: none
;prefix = /path/to/pools/$pool

; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
user = jithinvijayan
group = staff

; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
; Valid syntaxes are:
;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv4 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   '[ip:6:addr:ess]:port' - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv6 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses
;                            (IPv6 and IPv4-mapped) on a specific port;
;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = 127.0.0.1:9074
```

**Note:** Today I created one Laravel project after that I run the composer update command I got an error like `Composer: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size exhausted` but I fixed that issue with memory limit configurations in `php.ini`.